# Evaluate DataTable Expression

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a DataTable which is built from reading an Excel file (using OLEDB connection).  I would like to add a column which contains a comma separated list of the values in all the columns.

So if I have FirstName, LastName, Address then I want a 4th column which is a comma-separated concatenation of FirstName, LastName and Address.  I would rather not iterate over the records, because there could be 100,000's to 1,000,000's of records.  Is there a way to do this in the SQL statement?  I have `"select * from [" + sheetName[i] + "]"` where `sheetName[i]` is the current sheet name of the current loop (looping over X number of sheets).

In the end I am building a completely different DataTable containing columns in which I will be using to do SqlBulkCopy to a table in my SQL Server database. I added columns I needed for this bulk copy and then Merged my datatable from the Excel sheet to the end of my newly created DataTable.  Then I added a new column where I used. Expression to comma-separate my fields from Excel sheet datatable.  However, my new DataTable must be in exact form as the table i am doing bulk copy into.  So I want to delete the columns not in my SQL table, but I get error (which makes sense) when I try to delete these columns since they are a part of the Expression for one of the other columns.

So, is there a way to either query the Excel file to concatenate a comma-separated new column?  Or to force evaluation on the datatable Expression so that it evaluates the expression and stores the evaluated string to that column rather than using the Expression solely?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **System.Data.DataTable** in the .NET Framework you can make use of the Expression Property that is available for a **DataColumn**. It is talked about at this link [DataColumn.Expression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Below is some simple code to illustrate using the **Expression** property to concatenate your columns together into a comma delim string in the DataTable itself.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

// create the columns 
DataColumn firstNameColumn = new DataColumn();
firstNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
firstNameColumn.ColumnName = "FirstName";
firstNameColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;

DataColumn lastNameColumn = new DataColumn();
lastNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
lastNameColumn.ColumnName = "LastName";
lastNameColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;

DataColumn addressColumn = new DataColumn();
addressColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
addressColumn.ColumnName = "Address";
addressColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;

// this column uses an Expression to concatenate others together in comma delim
DataColumn concatColumn = new DataColumn();
concatColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
concatColumn.ColumnName = "Concatenated";
concatColumn.Expression = "FirstName + ', ' + LastName + ', ' + Address"; 

// add columns to DataTable 
table.Columns.Add(firstNameColumn);
table.Columns.Add(lastNameColumn);
table.Columns.Add(addressColumn);
table.Columns.Add(concatColumn); 

// add some rows
DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
row1["FirstName"] = "John";
row1["LastName"] = "Doe";
row1["Address"] = "123 East Street";
table.Rows.Add(row1);

DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
row2["FirstName"] = "Bill";
row2["LastName"] = "Smith";
row2["Address"] = "444 North Avenue";
table.Rows.Add(row2); 

// simple iteration to print out the concatenated column
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
   Console.WriteLine(dr["Concatenated"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to query the Excel file to concatenate a comma-separated new column?

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
select 
    *,
    FirstName + ", " + LastName + ", " + Address AS AllFields
from [" + sheetName[i] + "]"
```

Also if you have a specific destination format I would recommend explicitly stating the columns rather than using `"*"`:

```
select 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Address,
    FirstName + ", " + LastName + ", " + Address
from [" + sheetName[i] + "]"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I do not know the columns coming in.  These Excel files are coming from clients and are variable in length of columns and names.

Comment: @user3495483 so then you do you know which columns are for first name, last name, and address?

Comment: What I am doing is I created this app by which one of our employees will view the Excel file (via a DataGrid having datatable stored from Excel file).  Then they are mapping Name, Address1, State and Zip to the column names.  So I know which columns I need from the Excel file.  There are other column in my other datatable which are fed from other variables.  The big issue is I want to have a column which stores orig record from Excel file (comma-separated).  I used DataColumn.Expression, but the moment I try to delete the orig columns, it fails since using Expression.